# Redefining variables of a Java Class during an onCreate call?

Tags: java, constructor, initialization, member

```
public class Country implements ICountry {
   int stability = 2;
}

Country poland = new Country(stability = 3);
```

What I'm trying to do is extend an interface(ICountry) with a new class("Country") that has a few default values.  I want to know if it's possible to redefine some of those defaults when creating a new instance of the Country class.  The last line of code in my example is what I currently have as my attempt to accomplish this, but my IDE is warning me that 'stability cannot be resolved to a variable'.

My questions is, is it possible to redefine some of an object's default values when instantiating a class without constructing a method?

I'm just starting to learn Java and Android programming on my own, so if you think I referred to something with the wrong terminology please correct me.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is to define a constructor of `Country` that accepts a *parameter* and assigns it to a field, like so:

```
public class Country implements ICountry {
   int stability = 2; // the default

   public Country() {
        // no parameters, no assignments
   }

   public Country(int stability) {
       // declares parameter, assigns to field
       this.stability = stability;
   }
}
```

You can then create multiple instances of this class, like this:

```
Country unitedKingdom = new Country(); // 2 is the value of stability, taken from the default
Country poland = new Country(3); // 3 is the value of stability
```

The reason you need to have two constructors is that the version with no parameters (the "*default*", or "*implicit*" constructor) is generated if you haven't specified one, but once you specify a constructor, it won't be generated any more.

An alternate, and equivalent syntax for the default constructor could be:

```
public class Country implements ICountry {
   int stability; // declare field, but don't assign a value here

   public Country() {
        this.stability = 2; // instead assign here, this is equivalent
   }
}
```

Both this version and the previous version of the default constructor result in the same effect, but is generally a matter of preference.

There are languages that use the syntax you have shown, they're called "*named parameters*", but Java doesn't have them.

Answer (score 0):

This is what overloaded constructors are for:

```
public Country(int stability)  
{
   this.stability=stability;
}
```